# Summary with header and footer i-Report 5.0.1

Tags: jasper-reports

I am checking a property 'Summary with Page header and Footer' in i-report 5.0.1
I have some total daily balances , number of debits items etc printing in summary band 
and I have some static text printing in Last Page footer also.What happens is

if I check the above property 'Summary with Page header and Footer'  summary is getting overlapping with Last page footer text

if not checked , no problem exists, How to solve it out ??? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by following these steps:

1. Navigate to the properties of all the static text present in the Last Page footer .
2. Find the property called **'Position Type'**
3. Set the property to **'Float'**

This should do the trick

thanks.